# Python Excel Writer (xlswriter) Insert Image from URL

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, urllib, xlsxwriter

How can I insert an image **from URL** (http) with xlswriter? This is from documentation:

```
worksheet.insert_image('B2', 'python.png')
```

or

```
worksheet1.insert_image('B10', '../images/python.png')
```

But this is only for file path. I want to add image from URL from a Web Server. Can you help?

Comment: You mean you want to hotlink to images?

Comment: Is it an option to download it to a temporary folder first?

Comment: Tim: I can get its data with urllib.request.urlopen(url).read() but after that, I don't know what can I do. Rickard: No, just inserting from URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = "http://abcdef.com/picture.jpg"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
file = open("image.jpg", "wb")
file.write(data)
file.close()
worksheet.insert_image('B2', 'image.jpg')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
# Read an image from a remote url.
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/' + \
      'master/examples/logo.png'

image_data = BytesIO(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

# Write the byte stream image to a cell. Note, the filename must be
# specified. In this case it will be read from url string.
worksheet.insert_image('B2', url, {'image_data': image_data})
```

http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_images_bytesio.html